# How to receive multiple UDP datagram packets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I create a small demo, which has the function is : 
 - In UDPClient: 
 + user input two sentence : sentenceA and sentenceB 
 + than pass them to UDPServer 
 
 - In UDPServer : 
 + those two sentences will be
   capitalized 
 + pass those two capitalized sentences back to UDPClient 
 
The problem is, when I pass two sentence from UDPClient to UDPServer
For example: "aa" and "bb" . So, in UDPServer I can exactly get "aa" and "bb" . But when I return capitalized sentences : "AA" and "BB" from UDPServer to UDPClient, I can only get "AA". How do I get exactly both "AA" and "BB" in UDPClient after the processing ? 
Here is my code : 
UDP Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class UDPClient extends Thread {

static int port = 1234;

public UDPClient() {

}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run();
    while (true) {
        try {
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(5678);
            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData1 = new byte[1024];

            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

            System.out.println("\nInput sentenceA : " );
            String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
            System.out.println("Input sentenceB : " );
            String sentence1 = inFromUser.readLine();
            sendData = sentence.getBytes();
            sendData1 = sentence1.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 1234);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(sendData1, sendData1.length, IPAddress, 1234);
            clientSocket.send(sendPacket1);

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String modifiedSentenceA = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            String modifiedSentenceB = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("FROM SERVER : " + " sentenceA : " + modifiedSentenceA + ", sentenceB : " + modifiedSentenceB);

            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);;
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException {
    Thread t = new UDPClient();
    t.start();
}
}
```

UDPServer :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;


public class UDPServer extends Thread{


public UDPServer(){

}

@Override
public void run() {
    super.run(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(1234);

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData1 = new byte[1024];
        while(true){
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            String sentence1 = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("RECEIVED " + sentence + " sentence1 : " + sentence1);

            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
            String b = sentence1.toUpperCase();

            sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
            sendData1 = b.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
            DatagramPacket sendPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(sendData1, sendData1.length, IPAddress, port);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket1);


        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread serverThead = new UDPServer();
    serverThead.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
String modifiedSentenceA = new String(receivePacket.getData());
String modifiedSentenceB = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

Your client is only executing one receive. You're printing the received packet twice, but it's the same packet.

Comment: I try to declare 2 packets in Client, then I take the data from those 2 packets , but nothing is change .

Comment: No, you *aren't* declaring two packets  for receive. You are declaring two packets which are *sent,* not received, and you don't take any data from them: you send it. You are declaring *one* packet for receive, and you are receving into it *once*, and printing it twice. Why would anything change between the two prints? You don't appear to understand your own code.